# Ruby gem for scheduling and managing cron jobs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron

I have a web application, on which users can schedule different pre defined tasks. The user can schedule these tasks as per his convenience (Say task1 for last_x_hours every Tuesday 12.00 am, and so on)

The feature is just like scheduling cron jobs, however this is automated and happens via rails web app interface.

Is there a ruby gem for this?

I have come across `Resque`, `delayed_jobs` and `Sidekiq`, but they all seem to be for the case when you want to run certain tasks asynchronously.

Also, there is the `whenever` gem, but it seems to be the ruby way of defining cron jobs.

What I really want is something that can dynamically manipulate cron jobs and add or delete user defined cron jobs at runtime.
Am I missing something here?

Comment: How about https://github.com/jmettraux/rufus-scheduler

Comment: @MarekLipka Can we add more jobs at runtime using whenever? Say, when I start the web application, there are no jobs running, and users add the jobs by themselves, and I don't have to do any deploy changes / commit some new jobs? 


From the examples I am reading, it seems like cronjobs are added on each deploy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can checkout the Clockwork ruby gem. Based simple DSL and runner and for more advanced feature check out the Rufus-Scheduler gem.